# How to export DataFrame to Html with utf-8 encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I keep getting:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 265-266: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when I try:

```
df.to_html("mypage.html")
```

here is a sample of how to reproduce the problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [u'Rue du Gu\xc3\xa9, 78120 Sonchamp'], "b": [u"some other thing"]})
df.to_html("mypage.html")
```

the list of elements in `"a"` are of type `"unicode"`.

when I want to export it to csv it works because you can do:

```
df.to_csv("myfile.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: This works fine on python 3, presumably you're using python 2?

Comment: @EdChum I've personally run into this on Python2.7 numerous times.

Comment: @EdChum python 2.7.6

Comment: @YOBA HTML generation is neither fast nor vectorize-able. I usually just iterate over records, and use something like [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in other code.  Your sample code has a Unicode string that has been mis-decoded as `latin1`, `Windows-1252`, or similar, since it has UTF-8 sequences in it.  Here I undo the bad decoding and redecode as UTF-8, but you'll want to find where the wrong decode is being performed:

```
>>> s = u'Rue du Gu\xc3\xa9, 78120 Sonchamp'
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
u'Rue du Gu\xe9, 78120 Sonchamp'
>>> print(s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
Rue du Gué, 78120 Sonchamp
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't solve my problem, still getting the same error even though I applied it to all the the elements of "a" in the dataframe: df["a"] = df.apply( lambda x: x["a"].encode('latin1').decode('utf8'), axis=1)

Comment: @YOBA are you sure the strings are supposed to be Unicode?  The error you are getting is typical of using `.decode` on an already decoded Unicode string in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 10):

The way it worked for me:

```
html = df.to_html()

with open("dataframe.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.writelines('<meta charset="UTF-8">\n')
    file.write(html)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is actually in using `df.to_html("mypage.html")` to save the HTML to a file directly. If instead you write the file yourself, you can avoid this encoding bug with pandas.

```
html = df.to_html()
with open("mypage.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

You may also need to specify the character set in the head of the HTML for it to show up properly on certain browsers (HTML5 has UTF-8 as default):

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

This was the only method that worked for me out of the several I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to keep the output to html, you could try cleaning the code in a numpy array before writing to_html.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [u'Rue du Gu\xc3\xa9, 78120 Sonchamp'], "b": [u"some other thing"]})

def clean_unicode(df):
   *#Transforms the DataFrame to Numpy array*
   df=df.as_matrix()
   *#Encode all strings with special characters* 
   for x in np.nditer(df, flags=['refs_ok'], op_flags =['copy', 'readonly']):
         df[df==x]=str(str(x).encode("latin-1", "replace").decode('utf8'))
   *#Transform the Numpy array to Dataframe again*
   df=pd.DataFrame(df)
   return df

df=clean_unicode(df)
df.to_html("Results.html') -----> Success!
```