# exporting dataframe into dataframe format to pass as argument into next program

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export

I have certain computations performed on Dataset and I need the result to be stored in external file.

Had it been to CSV, to process it further I'd have to convert again to Dataframe/SFrame, which is again increasing lines of code.

Here's the snippet:

```
train_data = graphlab.SFrame(ratings_base)
```

Clearly, it is in SFrame and can be converted to DFrame using

```
df_train = train_data.to_dataframe()
```

Now that it is in DFrame, I need it exported to a file without changing it's structure. Since the exported file will be used as Argument to another python code. That code must accept DFrame and not CSV.

I have already check out in [place1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678467/export-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-table-image), [place2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894576/how-to-export-dataframe-to-html-with-utf-8-encoding), [place3](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_saving_dataframe_as_csv.html), [place4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-csv-file) and [place5](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Serialization)

P.S. - I'm still digging for Python serialization, if anyone can simplify
it in the context would be helpful

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. If you have a dataframe why do you need to export it to another dataframe? " I need the result to be stored in external file" Have you tried pickle?

Comment: @DeepSpace I need dataframe into an external file, the way csv's are done. This external file is then planned for other program to be given in arguments. I hope this clears the doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use HDFS format as it's supported by `Pandas` and by `graphlab.SFrame` and beside that HDFS format is very fast.

Alternatively you can export Pandas.DataFrame to Pickle file and read it from another scripts:

```
sf.to_dataframe().to_pickle(r'/path/to/pd_frame.pickle')
```

to read it back (from the same or from another script):

```
df = pd.read_pickle(r'/path/to/pd_frame.pickle')
```

Comment: pickle is the concept of Serialization, but I wonder if I can pass a pickled file in arguments. Is it possible? if so how do I unpickle it?

Comment: @Tejas, there is an example in the answer: `df = pd.read_pickle(r'/path/to/pd_frame.pickle')`

Comment: I had doubt in terms of passing it via Arguments. Anyways, I'll try it out. Much appreciated for your contribution.

Comment: I have popularity model from GraphLab any ideas how can I pickle it? I pickled it but while reading it returns error saying `Is a directory`